# get maximum length matching string from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multi dimensional array  and i have another array

CODE :

SINGLE ARRAY calles as A

```
Array
(
    [pattern] => 91919089
)
```

MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY called as b

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 42
        [1] => VIETNAM
        [2] => 84
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 46
        [1] => 3253
        [2] => 235
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 48
        [1] => india
        [2] => 91
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 49
        [1] => india
        [2] => 919
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 50
        [1] => india
        [2] => 9191
    )
```

Multi dimensional array  called as c

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 42
        [1] => VIETNAM
        [2] => 84
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 46
        [1] => 3253
        [2] => 235
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 48
        [1] => india
        [2] => 89
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 49
        [1] => india
        [2] => 089
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 50
        [1] => india
        [2] => 9089
    )
```

Here we can see that pattern 91919089 is matched with 3rd 4th and 5th element  of array b and key of 2 of each is 91,919 and 9191 respectively  and 5[2]i want result that 9191. = 9191 which is maximum matching string of pattern 91919089 so result is 5

suppose if  i will remove 5th element from multi dimensional array then must give me result that 4th is matching with 919. and if no match found then need to match from another array c from **end to start postion** here we can see in array c 3,4,5 element have 2nd keys are  89,089,9089 respectively and match 9089

Please help me out 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why (how) the pattern matches to 3rd, 4th and 5th element of array b?

Comment: because 3[2]=91,4[2]=919,5[2]=9191 in which pattern 91919089  maximum matching length  with element of 5 which is 9191 so answer is 5th element

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code block.

```
$a=array("pattern"=>"91919089");
$b=array("1"=>array("42","VIETNAM","84"),"2"=>array("46","3253","235"),"3"=>array("48","india","91"),"4"=>array("49","india","919"),"5"=>array("50","india","9191"));
$c=array("1"=>array("42","VIETNAM","84"),"2"=>array("46","3253","235"),"3"=>array("48","india","89"),"4"=>array("49","india","089"),"5"=>array("50","india","9089"));
        $count=0;
        $pos=0;
        $val=0;
        $arr=array();
        foreach ($b as $b1)
        {
            $count++;
            foreach ($b1 as $b2)
            {
                $len=strlen($b2);
                $string=$a['pattern'];
                $parts = array();
                for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
                {
                    $parts[] = substr($string, 0, $len);
                    $string = substr($string, $len);
                }
                if($b2 == $parts[array_search($b2, $parts)])
                    $arr[]=array("pos"=>$count,"val"=>$b2);
            }
        }
        if(sizeof($arr)!=0)
        {
            foreach ($arr as $ele)
            {
                if($val < $ele['val'])
                {
                    $pos=$ele['pos'];
                    $val=$ele['val'];
                }
            }
            echo "Matching element is: " . $val . " at position " . $pos ."th in b.";
        }
        else
        {
            $count=0;
            foreach ($c as $c1)
            {
                $count++;
                foreach ($c1 as $c2)
                {
                    $len=strlen($c2);
                    $string=$a['pattern'];
                    $parts = array();
                    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
                    {
                        $parts[] = substr($string, 0, $len);
                        $string = substr($string, $len);
                    }
                    if($c2 == $parts[array_search($c2, $parts)])
                        $arr[]=array("pos"=>$count,"val"=>$c2);
                }
            }
            if(sizeof($arr)!=0)
            {
                foreach ($arr as $ele)
                {
                    if($val < $ele['val'])
                    {
                        $pos=$ele['pos'];
                        $val=$ele['val'];
                    }
                }
                echo "Matching element is: " . $val . " at position " . $pos ."th in c.";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "Matching element not found in any of the array.";
            }
        }
```